# How do I chain multiple where and orWhere clause in laravel from an Array

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array

```
$user_lgas = ['lga1', 'lga2', 'lga3', ...];
```

I want to write a scopeSearch to get records base on user lgas
something like

```
$query->where('lga', $user_lgas[0])->orWhere('lga', $user_lgas[1])->orWhere('lga', $user_lgas[2]) ...
```

I want to generate this query dynamically from the array, but the logic is kind of complicated for me. Please any Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Laravel Documentation you should be able to use `whereIn()` or `whereNotIn()` with an array.

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
 
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereNotIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

So for your example

```php
$query->whereIn('lga',$user_lgas)->get();
```

For more details see: [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: When someone asks a basic question in 2022, you can be sure that it is a duplicate question.  Please flag/vote to close duplicates instead of answering.  Answering duplicates prevents the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from doing its important job.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a whereIn instead.

```php
$query->whereIn('lga', $user_lgas)
```

Comment: When someone asks a basic question in 2022, you can be sure that it is a duplicate question.  Please flag/vote to close duplicates instead of answering.  Answering duplicates prevents the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from doing its important job.